# Sitecore Publish Restrictions Window - Hide tab

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, restrictions, sitecore8.1

Can I restrict the show of these tabs? Is this via a Core DB security setting?
or is it in configurations?
I do not want to show the target tab to my users.

[Image of the dialog I am referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDwfi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot restrict the tabs you have specified. However, you can do the following:

Override the Sitecore UI XML and write a custom code to check the roles before rendering the tab

The XML to override is the **Set Publishing.xml** and the path is **Website\sitecore\shell\Applications\Content Manager\Dialogs\Set Publishing**

The reason why you cannot put restriction on the tab is because when the form loads, it you directly load all the tabs. There is no check of the user role.

**EDIT 1:** More information is available on my post https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2016/04/24/sitecore-custom-publish-restriction/

Thanks

Comment: When you override the XML file, place it in the override folder found at `Website\sitecore\shell\Override\Applications\Content Manager\Dialogs`. Note that the folders in the Override folder does not exist. You will need to create them. This is to keep the standard.

Comment: Thank you Hishaam , Will try this.